# How many sequences $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_{10}$ could be formed with $a_i \in \{0, 1, 2\}$ such that $a_{i + 1} \neq 2$ if $a_i = 1$?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there is a sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5,a_6,a_7,a_8,a_9,a_{10}$ with $a_i \in [0,1,2]$ $\forall i = 1,2,....,10$ such that for $i = 1,2,3,4,....,9$, if $a_i=1$, then $a_{i+1} \ne 2$. How many sequences could be formed?

What we can do I think is makes branches then the branches have a pattern.

$3,8,21,55,....$
so the closed form will look like fibonacci
$A_n = f_{2n+2}$

[Link To AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/u819249h2835891p25105903)

Comment: I am getting $a_n = \operatorname{Fib}_{2n + 2}$ where fibonacci numbers start from $1, 1$ ($1$-based)

Comment: I think for $4$ length sequences, the answer is $55$ instead of $42$

Comment: I think you are correct I wrongly counted it sorry

Comment: No SMS style please: Sols $\to$ Solution.

Comment: edited already do u have any idea Prof, about this problem

Comment: @GregoriusWillson My proof goes like this $f_{len, 2}$ represents the number of valid sequences of length $len$ and $0, 1$ represents whether this value can be $1$ or not. $f_{n, 0} = 2f_{n - 1, 0} + f_{n - 1, 1}$ $f_{n, 1} = f_{n - 1, 0} + f_{n - 1, 1}$, and now it's induction. $f_{n, 0} = \operatorname{Fib}_{2n + 2}$ $f_{n, 1} = \operatorname{Fib}_{2n + 1}$ because base case $f_{0, 0} = f_{0, 1} = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_n$ be the number of sequences of length $n$ that end with $1$, and $v_n$ be the number of sequences of length $n$ that end with $0$ or $2$. Then $u_1=1, v_1=2$, and
$$u_{n+1}=u_n+v_n\text{ ($a_{n+1}
=1$ is always allowed)}$$
$$v_{n+1}=(u_n+v_n)+v_n=u_{n+1}+v_n\text{ ($0$ is always allowed, $2$ is allowed if $a_n\ne 1$)}$$
Now you can see that the sequence $(u_1,v_1,u_2,v_2,u_3,v_3,\ldots)$ is precisely the Fibonacci series!